# SPF records to send from different domains

Tags: email, domain

We have Civi installed on the main non profit domain (example.com) but have a project related to the non profit on its own domain (projectexample.com).

We need to be able to send emails to the sponsors from the sponsors@projectexample.com domain and all the sponsors are in the Civi install at example.com.

I know with Mailchimp, I can set it up to grab the CNAME records and apply it to the DNS records of the domain I want to validate but how would one go about it in this scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you're mistaking different settings. In CiviCRM you can declare different accounts. Go to Administer > CiviMail > Mail settings & From email Address. There you set what you need to use different accounts to send e-mailings. Have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/installation-and-basic-set-up/#from-email-addresses)?

The SPF setting has to be done where you manage your domains, on the registrar or server side, not in CiviCRM. And once again you can edit your DNS zone to add txt or SPF entries for the domains you want to use. Also add DKIM keys to improve delivrability.